# Azure Redis Cache: "role discovery data is unavailable"

Tags: azure, redis, azure-redis-cache

I'm trying to connect to an instance of [Azure Redis Cache](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/redis-cache/) from my local dev machine. I'm using [StackExchange.Redis](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis) like so:

```
var lazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
{
    return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(
        $"{redisServerUrl},abortConnect=false,ssl=true,password={redisServerKey},connectTimeout=10000,syncTimeout=10000");
});
```

When `lazyConnection` is called I get an `InvalidOperationException` with the message:

> "role discovery data is unavailable"

and this one-liner stack trace:

> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.get_CurrentRoleInstance()

Why is the exception thrown and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*StackExchange.Redis* tries to discover the RoleInstance name under the covers if you don't specify a *ConfigurationOptions.ClientName* value.  It is odd that you are getting this error bubbled out to your code because the code in question handles all exceptions and defaults back to returning the Computer name.

I suspect that if you add **",name=XXX"** to your connection string, the error will go away because you will avoid that code path.

Comment: It might be that I've seen the exception because I have the [OzCode](http://oz-code.com/) debugging extension installed in my Visual Studio.